# Node.js (для работы с Webpack) на IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, webpack

Приветствую.
Есть система, которая крутится на IIS. Нужно добавить Webpack, для работы с фронт-эндом. Соответственно, необходимо поставить Node.js. 
Для тестирования пишу стандартный http-сервер. Но совместно с IIS он не работает (на любом порту браузер ничего не отдаёт). 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно организовать их совместную работу? Или, может быть, есть готовые варианты для Webpack? Либо же есть удобные варианты других "сборщиков"?
 Спасибо.

Comment: Вы переусложняете. Вам нода нужна как рантайм для вебпака, а не как http сервер. Если вам нужно как-то отдельно настроенный вебсервер для разработки, то писать ничего не надо а можно проксировать webpack-dev-server к вашему иису

Comment: То есть правильно я понимаю, что исходная задача - просто подружить вебпак с клиентской частью .net проекта? Если да, могу рассказать как сейчас сделано у меня

Comment: Был бы вам очень признателен, так как в плане работы со сборщиками я начинающий, и было бы полезно опыт разбирающегося человека. Только это не .Net-проект. Система называется OpetText, серверная часть там на своём языке, крутится всё на IIS, и вот к клиентской части системы нужно просто прикрутить Webpack (хотя можно и любой другой сборщик). Спасибо.

Comment: я не знаю вашей специфики чтобы вам помочь, в .net проектах просто встречается один устаревший механизм который мешает сделать просто, плюс приключения со студией чтобы можно было одной кнопкой сделать. А смысл-то  - просто сделать js файл сборщиком и подключить к странице.

Comment: А для того чтобы отлаживаться с помощью iis вам надо либо внимательно прочитать документацию к webpack-dev-server и организовать проксирование, либо по-колхозному пересобирать бандл ручками при каждом добавлении  нового файлика, а для отладки без этого просто запускать вебпаковский вотчер. Ну то есть вебпак - это штука которая преобразует один js в другой js. Ей не надо работать в райнтайме кроме как для целей разработки.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду изучать документацию.